# Laravel Request is null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I generate an input throught jquery like this:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: results[0].geometry.location,
    title: address,
    draggable: true,
    zoom: 19,
    icon: pinImages,
    shadow: pinShadows
});
lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
$("#lng").html("<input type=hidden name=lng value=" + lng + ">");
$("#lat").html("<input type=hidden name=lat value=" + lat + ">");
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (marker) {
    latLng = marker.latLng;
    lat = latLng.lat();
    lng = latLng.lng();
    $("#lng").html("<input type=hidden name=lng value=" + lng + ">");
    $("#lat").html("<input type=hidden name=lat value=" + lat + ">");
});
```

In html it looks like:

```
<div id="lat" value="53.486755"><input type="hidden" name="lat" value="53.4867546"></div>

<div id="lng" value="-2.054067"><input type="hidden" name="lng" value="-2.054066599999942"></div>
```

Which to me looks absolutely fine. Now when form is submitted controller is being called:

```
public function updateEntity(EntityRequestUpdate $request)
{
          dd($request->input('lat'));
```

However data dump is giving me null. Why would it be happening?

EntityRequestUpdate:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:100',
        'type' => 'required|exists:entity_types,type',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:100',
        'building_name' => 'nullable',
        'address' => ['required','max:191', new Address],
        'town' => ['required','max:191', new Hyphens],
        'postcode' => ['required','max:191', new Postcode],
        'telephone' => ['nullable','max:191', new Telephone],
        'ical' => 'nullable|active_url|max:191',
        'eventbrite' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'tags' => 'nullable|max:255',
        'url' => 'nullable|max:191',
        'video' => 'nullable|max:191',
        'bio' => 'nullable|max:500',
        'main' => 'nullable|max:2000',
        'lat' => 'nullable',
        'lng' => 'nullable'
    ];
```

Comment: I assume `EntityRequestUpdate` is a request file of which no code has been displayed here?

Comment: i have added it now

Comment: What does: `public function authorize()` return within the request file?

Comment: it does return true, everything else works it's just lat and lng being null for somee reason

Comment: Add you js code, which does the form submit. Also, instead of `dd($request->input('lat'));` use this: `print_r(\Input::all()); exit;`

Comment: `name=lat` shoudn't this be `name="lat"` ?

Comment: I don't have js coode which submit form. It does straight to a route which triggers controller. @Option not really because jquery appends " " for you

Comment: are `<div id="lat"` and `<div id="lng"` inside the form ??

Comment: yes @Maraboc I doubled checked before posting a question. Thing it was working and suddenly it stopped

Comment: You mean it was in production and working and suddenly it stopped working without any code changes?

Comment: yeah it picks every other value and there are 24 values in form. but it doesn't pick up lat and lng

Comment: I got your code working fine.  How exactly is the form submitted?  Try creating [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the problem.  BTW, why do your `<div>`s have values?

Comment: <div> had a value just to test if it's retrieved from database correctly.